# Rails 4: custom validations with external records

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Hi I have a model called PurchasingGroup, a purchasing group has many Goals.

Goal model has 2 attributes: `no_of_users` and `discount`

I need to validate that the goals are consecutive, for example if I create a Goal with `no_of_users = 10` and `discount = 15` then the next goal I create must have greater values, otherwise I have to show the error to the user, right now Im making the validation in the `create` action of the controller, I know it is a bad practice so I want to know how to create this validation, I could not achieved it using custom validations in the model level.

I need to access the purchasing group and then check if the last group goal values are greater than or equal to the values of the new goal:

Below is the validation I have in the controller, it works but I want to do it right:

```
def create
        respond_to do |format|
            @purchasing_group = PurchasingGroup.find params[:purchasing_group_id]
            @goal = Goal.new goal_params
            @error_messages = ""
            if not @purchasing_group.goals.empty?
                if @purchasing_group.goals.last.no_of_users >= @goal.no_of_users
                    @error_messages = "The goals are consecutive! No. Users: must be greater than the previous goal value"
                end
                if @purchasing_group.goals.last.discount >= @goal.discount
                    @error_messages = "#{@error_messages}\nThe goals are consecutive! discount: must be greater than the previous goal value"
                end
            end
            #if there are no errors then we save the object
            if @error_messages.empty?
                if @goal.save
                    @goal.update_attributes purchasing_group_id: params[:purchasing_group_id]
                end
            end
            #In a js template I handle the errors, that is not relevant for this question.
            format.js
        end

    end
```

Comment: this `@goal` what you want validate, will be in same `@purchasing_group = PurchasingGroup.find(params[:purchasing_group_id])` ???

Comment: what association between `Goal` and `PurchasingGroup` ?

Comment: `PurchasingGroup` has_many `Goal`, and yes the @goal will be within the @purchasing_group once validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood you right, then:

```
validate :count_no_of_users

private

def count_no_of_users
  last_goal = PurchasingGroup.find(self.purchasing_group_id).goals.last
  error(:count_no_of_user, "Should be more than #{last_goal.no_of_user}") if self.no_of_user < last_goal.no_of_user
end
```

and same for `discount`

you can validate it in single or separate validations.

Comment: Dam!! yea you are right, Im an asshole I forgot I can query the PurchasingGroup also in custom validations. Thanks!